# MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) shuts down when not attached to Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt-display, shutdown

Maybe somebody else is having this same issue? I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) running OS X El Capitan. For some reason, anytime I unplug the laptop from the Thunderbolt Display, it will shut down. I need to hit the power button for it to come back to life. It shuts down pretty quickly most of the time, although I've seen it stay alive for 5-10 minutes at the most.

I'm in the System Profiler looking at the battery info and it reports everything is cool. Fully charged, 284 cycles, condition normal. Any guess what might be wrong with this? Is there something to try before I spend money getting the problem diagnosed?

Comment: Does this happen only when it is running on battery, or does it also happen when the charger is plugged in?

Comment: It happens when the charger is plugged in.

Comment: Totally sure it shuts down? In that case, I would reinstall OS X before spending money. What happens to me is that the computer goes to sleep. Closing and opening the lid several times brings the Mac back from sleep.

Comment: Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but: once it has apparently shut down and you hit the power button for it to come back, do you get the Apple logo and loading bar, or are you more or less immediately at the login screen?

Comment: To both commenters, yes now that you mention it it's a little weird. The keyboard is still backlit when it "shuts down". Then I guess it takes a moment and goes dark. If I hit the power button afterward @Asmus I do get the Apple logo & loading bar.

Comment: If it does shutdown, there should be a "shutdown code" in the syslog.    Please issue the command: `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"`  Please post the results.

Comment: Turned out this was some serious "problem with the logic board" idk which one but Tekserv in NYC could not repair it and it was sent off to Apple where the repair cost around $550.

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting the SMC (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and the NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)